# Different scroll margins at top and bottom of window?

Tags: scrolling

**Q:** is there a way to set different scroll margins at the top and bottom of a window?

The variable `scroll-margin` (defined in the C source code) sets how many lines of text that Emacs displays, at a minimum, at the top and bottom of a window:

> Number of lines of margin at the top and bottom of a window.
>   Recenter the window whenever point gets within this many lines
>   of the top or bottom of the window.

I'd like to use `scroll-margin` for the bottom of the window, but don't want it at the top (e.g., a positive value at the bottom, but 0 at the top).  Is there a way to do so?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but in all likelihood `scroll-margin` is not the right tool for the job. You may need some function to put on `post-command-hook` to determine whether to scroll the window.

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment, finding out how many lines are visible around point seems highly nontrivial, considering wrapped lines, hidden text and the like. I suspect the necessary information is easily available only inside the display code. You could try submitting a feature request to allow (for example) a cons `(top . bottom)` for `scroll-margin`.

Comment: You might be interested in playing with the `window-scroll-functions` hook (which takes two arguments) and putting a `recenter` command into a function attached to that hook and then use a setting of `(setq scroll-conservatively 101)` -- in essence, you define when recentering occurs and turn off the built-in auto-scroll.  Something like `(when (and (>= (point) (window-end nil t)) (not (pos-visible-in-window-p (point) (get-buffer-window (current-buffer) (selected-frame))))) (recenter))`

Comment: @lawlist: thanks for the suggestion, but the end of the docstring reads "Warning: Do not use this feature to alter the way the window is scrolled.  It is not designed for that, and such use probably won't work."

Comment: Interesting question, I am wondering why there is no comments/vote on the answer provided by PythonNut.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```el
(defun my-define-scroll-margins (&rest _args)
  (interactive)
  (with-demoted-errors
    (let ((computed-margin
            (if (> (cdr (nth 6 (posn-at-point)))
                  (/ (window-body-height) 2)) 5 0)))
      (setq
        scroll-margin computed-margin
        smooth-scroll-margin computed-margin))))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook #'my-define-scroll-margins)
```

Note that this is theoretically inefficient, but performance on my lame computer seems unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Oh hey heads up. I just realized that this wasn't exactly answer to the original question. I just arrived her via search looking for a way to calculate the `scroll-margin` based on window height. Hope it's useful to somebody though.

Thanks to [@PythonNut](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2642/pythonnut), I was able to take their answer to this question and improve it closer to my preferences.

Just change the `minimum-window-height` and `percent-margin` variables to your preferences, and stick this in your config.

If you're using Doom Emacs like me, it can go into your `config.el` file.

```el
(defun my/define-scroll-margins ()
  "Set the scroll margins dynamically based on the current window height."
  (let ((minimum-window-height 14))
    (let ((percent-margin 0.1))
      (setq scroll-margin
            (if (<= (window-body-height) minimum-window-height)
                0
              (floor (* (window-body-height) (* percent-margin 2))))))))
(add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook #'my/define-scroll-margins)
```